# What is the meaning of pointer to non-existing struct as a member-variable in another struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, declaration, incomplete-type

I have seen blocks of code in C like this:

```
struct Struct1
{
    struct Struct2* var;
}
```

and I wonder what exactly is the meaning of `Struct2` in this example.In this code that is the first time when the name `Struct2` is used.

Comment: `Struct2` is another struct that has presumably been declared somewhere.

Comment: That depends entirely on what the real structures' names and purposes are. Your question needs more context. One can point to a declared-but-incomplete type just fine, using a _forward declaration_. Perhaps start at the latter in your searches.

Comment: @aschepler Why are no there forward declarations in C? Forward declaration - is a normative term neither in C nor in C++. It just means introducing a name without  its complete definition. It seems you are confusing terms the forward declaration and the elaborated type specifier.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oops, right, I misinterpreted a sentence. But a declaration like `struct S;` is much less useful in C than in C++ and is usually not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `struct Struct2` is an incomplete type (provided that there is no definition of the structure before the declaration of the structure Struct1). It can be defined somewhere else if the definition of the structure is required. But a pointer to this type like that

```
struct Struct2 *var;
```

is a complete type.

For example you can declare a structure `struct List` the following way

```
struct List
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};
```

In this declaration there is not required the complete definition of the structure `struct Node`. The structure `struct List` contains two pointers to the first and the last nodes of a list.

And then somewhere below or even in another header you can define the structure `struct Node` like for example

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

Comment: Hey, just saw this answer. I'm wondering - what happens if we use struct List, and then point to a struct other than Node? For example, let's say we declare test_struct structure, then declare int variable inside it. Then we point by pointers inside List to it. An error is shown - pointing to an incomplete type Node. Okay, then we add struct Node and int variable inside, we don't change pointers to test_struct. What I mean is - everything is fine as long as test_struct has the same size as Node struct has, right?

Comment: If we add for example double, which is 8 bytes on my machine to the Node struct, then the pointer from List struct will try to dereference 8 bytes from test_struct (size of Node struct), which is incorrect because test_struct is 4 bytes (has 1 int variable inside it), am I right?